# Procmail Replace / Add Subject to an Empty Subject Field

Tags: procmail

I have a recipe that cannot seem to match the address.

I tried these:

```
* ^From.*address9\@gmail\.com

* ^From.*address9@gmail.com

* ^From.*address\[0-9\]\@gmail\.com

* ^From.*address\d\@gmail\.com

* ^From.*address\d@gmail.com
```

but none of the above-mentioned works... I am totally lost. It looks like regular expressions have its own logic and patterns in procmail.

Here is my full recipe. The address to match has this 9 at the end and it's gmail.com When I put any other email address into this * ^From.* field it works OK, but this one doesn't... Here is my full recipe. The conditions to match are: to add a tag [New Report] when it comes from address9@gmail.com and the subject field is empty. I would really be thankful if somebody could advise please, as I am about to go nuts trying to understand where is the mistake here.

```
:0 fhw
* ^From.*address9\@gmail\.com 
* ^Subject:\/.+
| /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [New Report]$MATCH"
```

Would also be grateful for any pointers how to trouble shoot it. Many thanks in advance!

The header looks like this:

```
From: Name Lastname <address9@gmail.com>
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 20:37:17 +1200
Message-ID<CADxD3vdy5cW55mogOK5+543ngU7iFKjJcpDV3Q4YL772F=LdQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject:
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the entire `From:` header line which you are attempting, but failing to match on? The regex looks fine, though of course there is no need to backslash `@`.

Comment: I added the header.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me - see update to my answer now. The Message-Id: at least doesn't look genuine though (should have a colon before the `<`)

Comment: That's just a typo I made during copy-paste. There is a colon in front of the <

Comment: You seem to be responding to comments quite rapidly, and yet you never clarified this question. Could you please [edit] to explain what exactly your problem is and why the answer you got is not acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are pretty simple actually. Nearly every character simply matches itself. So if you have (beginning of line) `F` `r` `o` `m` `:` followed by anything followed by `a` `d` `d` `r` `e` `s` `s` `9` ... it *should* match.

Procmail doesn't support various Perl extensions like `\d` or `\t`, and of course there is no need to backslash characters which don't have a special meaning in regex like `@`.  If you want to match a single digit that's `[0-9]` *without* any backslashes (those would change `[` and `]` back into literal matches).

`^Subject:\/.+` checks that there is at least one character in the `Subject:` header and collects it all into `$MATCH`. This *does not* check that the subject is empty. Perhaps you want something like

```
# \t is not supported, replace with a literal tab character
* ^Subject:[ \t]+$
```

where the `\t` should be replaced with a literal tab. Every message should contain a `Subject:` header so it will always be there, but if its value consists entirely of whitespace, that is considered an empty subject. And of course, if the header is empty, there is no need to capture its contents.

Reviewing your attempts, here are some comments on each.

- `^From.*address9\@gmail\.com`

  As suggested above, the backslash before `@` is superfluous, but harmless. This should match any header line which starts with `From` and which contains `address99@gmail.com` somewhere later on the same line.
- `^From.*address9@gmail.com`

  The unescaped dot matches any character, so this would also match `address9@gmailscom.example.org` for example.
- `^From.*address\[0-9\]\@gmail\.com`

  The square brackets are escaped, and thus matched literally. This will match any line which starts with `From` and which contains the literal text `address[0-9]@gmail.com` somewhere later on the line, which is unlikely in practice.
- `^From.*address\d\@gmail\.com`

  Procmail does not support the Perl escape `\d` for a digit, so this would match literally `addressd@gmail.com` on a header line starting with `From`.
- `^From.*address\d@gmail.com`

  As above, with the unescaped dot again matching any character in addition to a literal dot.

Having said that, your second condition would match if there is at least a single space after the colon in `Subject:` so again, it really *should* match in your test case unless there really is absolutely nothing in the `Subject:` header.

So anyway, if that was your problem, the `From:` recipe might actually have been matching, but the `Subject` condition was not matching.  With Procmail `VERBOSE` logging you would see each regex with "matched" or "no match" in the log file.

```
:0 fhw
* ^From.*address9@gmail\.com\>
* ^Subject:[    ]*$
| /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [New Report]"
```

(The added word boundary `\>` prevents `com` from matching if it is part of a longer word.)

Or perhaps you want to do this with any `Subject:` header? (This time I'm using a proper literal tab - check that you copy/paste this properly, though! There should be a space and a tab between `[` and `]`.)

```
:0 fhw
* ^From.*address9@gmail\.com\>
* ^Subject:[    ]*\/.*$
| /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [New Report] $MATCH"
```

For troubleshooting, perhaps have a look at http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

The Stack Overflow [Minimal Reproducible Example](/help/mre) guidance is also useful. Briefly, try to reduce the problem to the simplest input message and the simplest recipe which doesn't behave like you expect, then once you can't reduce it any further, take a good sharp look at what you are left with. Common causes of confusion include

- malformed input messages

  - Empty lines in what's supposed to be the headers?
  - Headers wrapped over multiple physical lines?
  - Pesky control characters where there aren't supposed to be, either in the message or in your Procmail script (don't use Windows editors`^W`)
- unwarranted assumptions

  - Regex doesn't work like you thought?
  - Procmail's regex dialect is different than e.g. Perl's? Online regex testers typically assume a Perl (or occasionally Javascript) regex feature set
  - Procmail matches against only the headers by default; some beginners miss this and are surprised when it doesn't find a string which is plainly there, only in the body
  - MIME content-transfer-encoding obscures the content you thought you knew was there?
  - Your regex really has to match a literal piece of text in the message; Procmail does no normalization e.g. to extract just the sender address in a convenient form for matching.

... Oh, and everyone's favorite: Make sure you set `SHELL=/bin/sh` right at the top of your recipe file. This has been the source of many otherwise completely mysterious failures over the years.

Here is a quick demo to demonstrate that your test case works for me:

```sh
tripleee@debian$ cat >test.msg
From: Name Lastname <address9@gmail.com>
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 20:37:17 +1200
Message-ID<CADxD3vdy5cW55mogOK5+543ngU7iFKjJcpDV3Q4YL772F=LdQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: 

No fooling
^D

tripleee@debian$ cat >test.rc
SHELL=/bin/sh
DEFAULT=/dev/null
VERBOSE=yes

:0 fhw
* ^From.*address9\@gmail\.com 
* ^Subject:\/.+
| /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [New Report]$MATCH"
^D

tripleee@debian$ procmail -m test.rc <test.msg 
procmail: [3717] Wed Jun 12 13:38:55 2019
procmail: Match on "^From.*address9\@gmail\.com"
procmail: Assigning "MATCH="
procmail: Matched " "
procmail: Match on "^Subject:\/.+"
procmail: Executing " /usr/bin/formail -i "Subject: [New Report]$MATCH""
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/dev/null"
procmail: Opening "/dev/null"
From address9@gmail.com  Wed Jun 12 13:38:55 2019
 Subject: [New Report] 
  Folder: /dev/null                             253
```

Comment: I was wondering how do you make this normal regular expression into this "weird" procmail's regular expression with its strange adjustments and its own rules?  /^From:\sName\sLastname\s\<address9\@gmail\.com$/ Is it possible at all?

Comment: The Perl whitespace shorthand `\s` corresponds to the character class `[  ]` with a space and a tab between the brackets which Ieused inea couple of places. The Perl one technically covers a few more characters, but nothing which makes sense in email headers. From a regex purity point of view, it's Perl's dialect which is weird (you can never know if backslash escapes a character or introduces a new special token) except for Procmail's special `\/` operator for capturing a match.

Comment: The regex you propose should perhaps account for possible variations in whitespace. It should really also cope with several different address formats to be completely general (no real name, real name as a comment in parentheses after the actual address, etc) as well as MIME encoding, which is a significant can of worms unto itself.

Comment: And you lack the final `>`; the address in your regex is actually malformed. Perhaps this was your problem all along?

Comment: Are you saying that I should replace all my \s (whitespace in regexp) with [ ] with a space and a tab between as per your previous examples? Also why is there no colon after *^From.* in procmail but there is always a colon after *^To:.* ? I haven't tried this regex yet where there is this final > missing, I just typed it in here  real quick to ask generally. Thanks

Comment: If you want to match `From:` then you should absolutely spell out the colon. There is a [pseudo-header which starts with `From ` (with a space)](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#from--) which is sometimes targeted by rules -- as indicated in the answer, your regex should match exactly the letters you see in the message, and usually be as specific as possible. And yes, your regex would be `^From:[  ]*Name[  ]+Lastname[  ]*<address9@gmail\.com>$` with a space and a tab between the square brackets, but usually a better expression would be `^From:(.*\<)?address9$gmail\.com\>`

Comment: Looking back at my comments, cursed be the mobile keyboard and sorry for the sloppy typing. The `$` in my previous comment should almost certainly be a `@`

Comment: That's OK triplee. Then your @ in your previous comment should also be escaped like this \@. What mobile keyboard are you using?

Comment: No, `@` is not a regex special. This is already mentioned in the answer.